# Datagridview paging does not ever fire

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datagridview, paging

i know the question may be silly , but i have been searching for 2 hours but with no result 
i have a data grid view with paging and when i select page 2 or any thing it never works and come back with page 1 here is the code

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="gvRatings" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20"
PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages" OnPageIndexChanged="gvRatings_PageIndexChanged" >
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="right" CssClass="Normal"/>
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateColumn >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkListingName" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
```

and this is the page load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            BindRatingsDG();
            BindRatingsStatsDG();
    }
```

and this is the paging event ,,

```
protected void gvRatings_PageIndexChanged(object sender, DataGridPageChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set grid view page index with the new page index selected
        gvRatings.CurrentPageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gvRatings.DataBind();
        BindRatingsDG();
    }
```

at the debug the arrow hit the load and the bind function but never hit the paging function ??
what am i doing wrong ?
thnx in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You should check the `Page.IsPostBack` flag in the PageLoad.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindRatingsDG();
        BindRatingsStatsDG();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing , even when i added postback check

Comment: the check come back with false and reload the page with GV page 1

Answer (score 0):

Your GridView is getting binded on every postback of the pager link you click.

You should modify your Page load function as below

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
     if(!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
        BindRatingsDG();
        BindRatingsStatsDG();
      }
}
```

Comment: Still nothing , even when i added postback check

Comment: the check come back with false and reload the page with GV page 1

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at gvRatings_PageIndexChanged function and check if it is at all called? If it is called then check your DataBinding where you are fetching data.

Comment: yah i put the breakpoint , but it never hit, that's why i am confused

Comment: Did you try using PageIndexChanging event instead of PageIndexChanged?

Comment: try  gvRatings.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

Comment: baby , it never hit the function ,, the code inside it is not the problem now i think , it's why it did not fire , or the breakpoint never hit